# accessing fieldnames as metadata in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper, mongoose, pymongo

I have a number of different documents in a mongo collection. 
The attrs are all numeric values.  I don't know apriori what the fieldnames are (I do but they can vary from doc to doc).

I want to write a program that

a) gets all the unique fieldnames in a collection 
b) finds the max and min value of each field in the collection

and then  reports it in a tabular form with rows "fieldname, maxvalue, minvalue" or in JSON that is equivalent. I am using pymongo but I don't have to, ruby or js or even java driver is fine.

How do I get programmatic access to the list of unique fieldnames in a collection?  That's 
the major question.  I can manage the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you main the list of used key inside your application as part of your application logic in some document inside the same collection or a meta-collection yourself or you have to iterate over all documents to figure out the list of keys...there is nothing in MongoDB helping you here since MongoDB is *schemaless*.

Comment: This. Alternatively you can iterate over the entire collection and create a run-time collection of unique field names but in almost all scenarios that's A Bad Idea (tm) ;)